# How to call pdftex.exe

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to call `pdftex.exe` from the command-line with a simple document that looks as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

But instead of my PDF I get the following output

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(c:/temp/1884874639.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on c:/temp/1884874639.log.
```

Is there some command-line switch that I'm missing? My invocation is `pdftex.exe -output-directory="c:\temp" 123.tex`.

Comment: Are you sure you do not want `pdflatex` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
% this file name is filename.tex
hello world
\bye
```

with `pdftex filename.tex`

Or try

```
% this file name is filename.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex filename.tex`

Comment: Thanks, went with `pdflatex`. Sucks that I have to post a Q on SE to figure this out.